# C# - Initialize multidimensional array [,] Using a For-Loop to make 100 * 100 int grid

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, 2d

I am wanting to create a 2d array to produce a grid of int values the size of the grid needs to be 100 * 100

**Example Grid**

```
1   2   3  .........100

101 102 103.........200

201 202 303.........300
```

I produced ths

```
    int rows = 100;
    int columns = 100;

    public int[,] InitIntArray() {
        int[,] grid = new int[rows,columns];
        int number = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i != rows; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j != columns; j++)
                grid[i, j] = number;
                number++;
        }

        return grid;
    }
```

When I use my code everything seems to work fine until I try to access the columns. all I get when I use **grid.getValue()** is **1**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missed one curvy

```
    for (int i = 0; i != rows; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j != columns; j++)
        {
            grid[i, j] = number;
            number++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: LOL thanks, I knew it would be something simple sometimes just need some fresh eyes on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
```

And the other for-loop

```
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        grid[i, j] = number;
        number ++;
    }
```

You might want to read on how for-loops work, http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/12/c-loops-examples/